# Meaning of “a tiger knows how to step, and a human doesn't”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I screenshot [11:27](https://youtu.be/aKW_THDHjXA?t=687). Please see below.

[image]

Comment: maybe it basically mean a tiger knows to get ready for battle and a human does not know how or how a tiger can get in shape of a certain type of walking that human cant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cats (including tigers) have a specific way of walking when hunting/stalking that involves putting their front feet down very gradually to minimize noise, shifting their weight, and then moving their back feet up to put them down in the same place that their front foot just left.

Humans, in comparison, are careless, clumsy, noisy beasts that have no hope of moving through a jungle quietly.

Answer (score 2):

To "step" is to place one foot in front of another.

The meaning is literal.  "A tiger knows how to put one foot in front of the other in the jungle (without being heard or snapping any twigs)"

Comment: Hey, that is right, what I wanted to imply but couldn't